# How do I access the data files belongs to a application in Android?

Tags: android

I don't how to do this task.
Using the `getpath()` method I can get the path of the database.

In the Terminal Emulator using commands I can see the database file which contains the queries that I have executed, the file is saved in the emulator memory.

How can I access that file from an android application. Is this possible? Please help me.

Comment: Is this a database you've created on the SD card or an internal db?

Comment: I created as internal Database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get `getContext().openFileInput()` to get files created by/for the current application.
These files are in  ***/data/data/com.you.application/ and have the uid/gid*** related to the app for security purposes